# PowerBI average below sum

Tags: powerbi

It is possible to add additional row in table in PowerBI below sum which will be average of every column?

[image]

Comment: It should be possible with an R Visual. Add the fields to the R visual, then create a new dataframe containing the averages for each column & append it with something like rbind.  There is no built in functionality to do this, the bottom row of a table can be totals but not any other metric.

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is not available in any PowerBI visual.

Answer (score 0):

While these feature is not directly available, you could achieve this effect using a row-based metric pattern and some clever formatting.